# No graba la fecha del datepicker

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows10

Tengo el proyecto funcionando correctamente con `Windows 7` y `Sql Server 2008` pero con `Windows 10` y `Sql Server 2014` no toma la fecha del `datepicker`, la graba como 01/01/0001.

A continuación imágenes del proyecto que funciona bien y el código que es el mismo. El CRUD funciona correctamente en el equipo con las versiones antes mencionadas pero al al tratar de grabar el registro en el equipo de `Windows 10` y `SQL Server 2014` lo graba con el formato antes mencionado y no es cargada la fecha en el `datagridview` ya que ese control maneja como fecha mínima una muy lejos de la que graba por defecto como 01/01/0001.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AppGameNote
{
    public partial class frmRecordatorio : Form
    {
        Recordatorio model = new Recordatorio();
        bool operation = false;
        DateTime fecha;

        public frmRecordatorio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            txtNombre.Text = string.Empty;
            txtDireccion.Text = string.Empty;
            txtTelefono.Text = string.Empty;
            dtmFecha.Text = dtmFecha.Value.ToShortDateString();
            txtDescripcion.Text = string.Empty;
            btnGrabar.Text = "Grabar";
            btnEliminar.Enabled = false;
            model.Id = 0;
            txtNombre.Focus();
        }

        private void frmRecordatorio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clear();
            PopulateDataGridView();
        }

        private void btnGrabar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Validation())
            {
                return;
            }

            model.Nombre = txtNombre.Text.Trim();
            model.Direccion = txtDireccion.Text.Trim();
            model.Telefono = txtTelefono.Text.Trim();
            model.Descripcion = txtDescripcion.Text.Trim();
            model.Fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(fecha);

            using (GameNoteEntities db = new GameNoteEntities())
            {

                if (model.Id == 0) //Insetar registro
                {
                    db.Recordatorios.Add(model);
                }
                else //Actualizar registro
                {
                    operation = true;
                    db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
                }

                try
                {
                   db.SaveChanges();
                    Clear();
                    PopulateDataGridView();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
                    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                            .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

                    // Join the list to a single string.
                    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

                    // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
                    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

                    // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
                    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
                }
            }

            if (operation)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registro actualizado", "Actualización de registros",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                operation = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Registro insertado", "Inserción de registros",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                operation = true;
            }

        }

        void PopulateDataGridView()
        {
            using (GameNoteEntities db = new GameNoteEntities())
            {
                dgvRecordatorio.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dgvRecordatorio.DataSource = db.Recordatorios.ToList<Recordatorio>();
            }
        }

        private void dgvRecordatorio_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvRecordatorio.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                model.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgvRecordatorio.CurrentRow.Cells["Id"].Value);
                using (GameNoteEntities db = new GameNoteEntities())
                {
                    model = db.Recordatorios.Where(r => r.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtNombre.Text = model.Nombre;
                    txtDireccion.Text = model.Direccion;
                    txtTelefono.Text = model.Telefono;
                    dtmFecha.Text = model.Fecha.ToShortDateString();
                    txtDescripcion.Text = model.Descripcion;
                }
                btnGrabar.Text = "Actualizar";
                btnEliminar.Enabled = true;
            }

        }

        private void btnEliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("¿Está seguro de eliminar el registro?", "Eliminación de registro", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                using (GameNoteEntities db = new GameNoteEntities())
                {
                    var entry = db.Entry(model);
                    if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
                    {
                        db.Recordatorios.Attach(model);
                    }
                    db.Recordatorios.Remove(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    PopulateDataGridView();
                    Clear();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registro eliminado con éxito");
                }
        }

        private bool Validation()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNombre.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe de ingresar el nombre", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtNombre.Focus();
                return true;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dtmFecha.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe de ingresar una fecha en formato dd/mm/aaaa", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                dtmFecha.Focus();
                return true;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDescripcion.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe de ingresar un descripción del recordatorio", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtDescripcion.Focus();
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //Valida que solo se ingresen digitos y espacios en blanco
        private void txtTelefono_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))

            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        //Valida que solo se ingresen letras y espacios en blanco
        private void txtNombre_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else if (Char.IsSeparator(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void dtmFecha_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dtmFecha.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Has verificado si el .net framework es el mismo que usas en win7 ?

Comment: @mhplur, ya solucione el problema, no tiene que ver con el framework, debí mover una línea del código donde se asigna el atributo fecha y funcionó, extraño, porque en Windows 7 tengo el código tal cual lo publique y funciona correctamente.